HTMX Boost and nprogress don't seem to work when going back one page
I wanted to add nprogress to a demo application and show the progress bar only on boosted requests. My first idea was to do it like this:
window.addEventListener('htmx:beforeRequest', (event) => {
    if(event.detail.boosted) {
        console.log(event);
        NProgress.start();
    }
});
window.addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest', (event) => {
    if(event.detail.boosted) {
        console.log("Done")
        console.log(event)
        NProgress.done();
    }
});

However, when going back in history the NProgressBar gets shown again (see video) even though I wouldn't expect it to show. I also created a demo Laravel application here.
Thank you in advance.

This looks like unconventional htmx to me. Why are you adding an event listener in javascript? With htmx you should add the htmx:afterRequest to the html element itself. What's the relevant html here? Your example isn't self-contained, it lacks context.
